# How to use allowDiskUse option in pyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I am getting following error when I am using **'Sort'** operation in **pyMongo**:

> OperationFailure: Executor error during find command: OperationFailed:
>   Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add
>   an index, or specify a smaller limit. // Werkzeug Debugger

I can not limit the number of records.

Please suggest me a way around. **TIA**

Answer (score 2):

```
db.example.aggregate(
   [
     {$match : {key : matchvalue }},
     {$sort : {sortkey : -1/1}}
   ],
   {
       allowDiskUse: true // creates temp files if sort limit(100 MB) exceeds
   } 
);
```

This might be helpful. Its good to use the aggregate pipeline for this kind of tasks as MongoDB provides many operators.

Comment: We can $project to skip unwanted fields in result.

Comment: allowDiskUse: true 
only for  +6.0v